# how can I move drawed image in canvas

Tags: html5-canvas

I want to move image move down three times and 10px,  in Canvas by animation.
for example code.org game !

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9nlmr.png)
like this!!!
how can I move image in canvas

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The HTML5 canvas works... well... like a real canvas. You can easily put paint on a canvas, but moving the paint around is difficult. The best way to change it is to just draw over it.

When you draw something to a html5 canvas, it stops being an object and becomes a bunch of RGB values. The usual way to handle animation in canvas is to clear the canvas and redraw the whole scene.

Comment: Thank you your answer, If I draw rectangle! Can move rectangle right 10px three time??  for code.... for(i=0; i<3; i++){ go foward !! }

Comment: @Bin_JJANNG Yes, when the code in your for-loop 1. calculates the new position of everything, 2. erases your canvas and 3. draws everything again on the new positions you calculated.

Comment: @Bin_JJANNG When you would like to ammend your question, please edit it. Comments are too short and don't allow formating for posting more than a line of code.

Comment: sorry...Because... I don't speak english well..  But I'm very thank you for your help

Comment: i want posting my code but i don't know how do it

Comment: @Bin_JJANNG edit your question and paste it there. Without linebreaks it's a pain to read and I will not do that.

Comment: ??? !!! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26830378/how-can-i-move-left-or-right-image-for-animate-in-canvas @Bin_JJANNG: please try learning from the answers you've been given.

Comment: @markE I try your answer, it go right sucessly but... It does't stop at 3 px...

Comment: @Philipp : You can do better than posting a comment as an answer to get points from an ultra-null user/question.